# In Paolo Bacigalupi's The Windup Girl, why are solar and wind power not utilized?

Tags: technology, energy, the-windup-girl

In "The Windup Girl", after the end of fossil fuels, humanity (or at least Thailand) has fallen back to use human and animal power as main energy source. Energy is either stored as food, or in mechanical form like in "kink springs" and flywheels.

Electrical energy is rarely used, almost exclusively for computers and radios, which are both a rarity. Where it is used, it is generated from mechanical work (e.g. hand cranks). There doesn't seem to be any mention of batteries, power grids, and (green) power plants.

What explains (in universe) the absence of these technologies?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [an IO9 interview on 2/26/2010](http://io9.com/5480532/ask-paolo-bacigalupi-about-windup-girl?comment=19874784#comments):

> **Q. Can you give us more background about what happened to solar panels, wind energy, hydroelectric power, and nuclear reactors in the Windup Girl world?**
>
> **A.** *Basically, I took all the different alternative energy sources that got
>   in my way, marched them out back, and shot them through the eye with a
>   spring gun (not much gunpowder in TWG, either).*
>
> *I had to do in oil shale, tar sands, hydrogen fuel cells, wave
>   generators, and a bunch others, too. Bloody work, I'll tell you.*
>
> *But I kept coal because it's dirty and stupid and plentiful, and we
>   use a lot of it.*
>
> ***At root, there was an aesthetic I was interested in, and I did
>   everything I could to reinforce that. If you look at it through the
>   lens of predictive science fiction, this story will definitely fail
>   for you.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Ask Paolo Bacigalupi About Windup Girl](http://io9.com/5480532/ask-paolo-bacigalupi-about-windup-girl?comment=19874784#comments)</sup></sub>

It's out of continuity, but it basically boils down to "they just don't exist here".

Comment: Not an in-universe explanation, but at least this explains the out of universe reason. Thanks!

Comment: Wave and tidal power could easily supply more energy than we need, it's just not currently half as practical as solar and wind, but it's easy to scale.